# Is my intuition of "If $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$" correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-factorization

I'm studying number theory and I was given this Theorem to look at:

> If $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$

I had the following intuition for the problem or a proof of sorts if you will.

**Intuitive Proof.** We take the assumption that $p$ can *in fact* divide $ab$. Then, this implies that $p$ is divided out by one of prime factors of $ab$. The prime factors of $ab$ can be thought of as the union of the sets of primes factors of $a$ and $b$. This would mean that $p$ is in the set of prime factors of $a$ or $b$. More concretely:

Let $S$ be the set of primes factors of $ab$ which we defined to be the union of the sets of the prime factors of $a$ and $b$. For example:

Let $A$ be the set of primes factors of $a$ and let $B$ be the set of prime factors of $b$. Then $S=A \cup B$

Now, if $p \mid ab$ then $p$ must belong to $S$ ($p \in S$) this, therefore, implies that $p \in A$ or $p \in B$.

So, that's my "intuitive proof". Does it make sense?

All feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

EDIT: $p$ is prime.

Comment: If $p$ is any number (prime or composite), then no.  For instance, $6 | 2 \cdot 3$, but $6 \not| 2$ or $6 \not| 3$

Comment: is $p$ a prime ? if not how about $60|6 \times 10$ ?

Comment: Indeed, as NasuSama pointed it's not always true. In fact it is characterization of primes numbers.

Comment: If $ab=pq$ and assume that $a=pq_1 + r_1$ and $b=pq_2 + r_2$ with $r_1 \neq 0$ and $r_2 \neq 0$ (these are the translation of $p$ does not divide $a$ nor $b$). Now, multiplying $a$ and $b$ we get : $ab = p[pq_1q_2 + q_2r_1 + q_1r_2] + r_1r_2$; but $r_1r_2 \neq 0$, contradicting the fact that $p$ divides $ab$. Is it right ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You would probably be better off asking a new question for something like this; in answer, however, the constraint you need on $r_1$ and $r_2$ is actually $0<r_i<p$ in order to assert non-divisibility by $p$, and this constraint is not sustained in the product $r_1 r_2$. I do remember seeing a similar proof along these lines, though; I think it involved assuming $p$ was minimal.

Comment: @NasuSama Sorry about that. Yes, $p$ is prime. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: You have $r_1 r_2< p^2$ and $r_1 r_2 = px$, which implies in particular that $x<p$. If $p$ is a minimal counterexample, then for a prime factor $q \mid x$, you can divide $q$ out of either $r_1$ or $r_2$, and repeat until $x=1$. This gives a factorization $p = r_1 r_2$, which contradicts $p$ being prime (or rather, irreducible, as it is defined when you get into generalizations in abstract algebra).

Comment: This idea works, provided you have already proved that every number has a *unique* prime factorization. Otherwise you can't rule out that one of a or b has another factorization that doesn't involve p. On the other hand, the present theorem is often used in proving unique factorization, so you must make sure your argument is not circular.

Comment: @Dustan Levenstein - You are right; I neglected the fact that $p$ must be *prime*. If $p$ is a *prime factor* of $ab$, then $p$ is in the set of *prime factors* of $ab$. But this set is the **union** of the set of *prime factors* of $a$ with the set of *prime factors* of $b$. So, $p$ must divide $a$ **or** $p$ must divide $b$.

Comment: Now you're just asking precisely the same question that the original poster asked in the first place, which my answer addresses. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. *However*, this part:

> The prime factors of $ab$ can be thought of as the union of the sets of primes factors of $a$ and $b$.

is (part of) the content of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. The statement that $p \mid ab$ implies $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$ is typically used as a lemma in proving the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, and therefore it is circular to use the latter to prove the former.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\cal P(n) =$ the set of prime factors of $n$. You sketched the following argument: $ $ for a prime $\,p$

$$p\mid ab\!\iff\! p\in\color{#c00}{\cal P(ab) = \cal P(a)\cup \cal P(b)}\!\iff\! p\in\cal P(a)\ \ {\rm or}\ \ p\in \cal P(b)\!\iff\! p\mid a\ \ {\rm or}\ \ p\mid b$$

But you did not provide any proof of the $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ theorem. In fact the converse is also true, the Prime Divisor Property implies the $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ theorem. A proof of their equivalence, or an implication between them, does not constitute a proof of either of them.

Probably you have some prior intuition that the $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ theorem is true from theorems you have learned about the *uniqueness* of prime factorization of integers (which, combined with the (trivial) *existence* of prime factorizations, constitues the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic*). If so, then it is *essential* to *explicitly* mention how the $\rm\color{#c00}{red}$ theorem is a *logical consequence* of these prior-proved results, so that you can convince the reader that the proof that you have in mind is *rigorous*.

Such rigor is especially necessary for results like this because we have such strong *empirical* (vs. logical) intuition about the integers that many people think that results like uniqueness of prime factorization is "obvious," with no rigorous proof required. Without any explicit justification offered in a proof, there is no way for the reader to judge its correctness. It leaves doubts: did the author think that it is "obvious", or did they have in mind one of many common erroneous proofs?

For many centuries no one noticed that uniqueness of prime factorizations required proof. Apparently either no one conceived of the possibility of nonuniqueness (or those who did thought that the proof was "obvious"). This was not corrected until $1801$, when Gauss plugged this gaping logical hole in his book *Disq. Arith.*, remarking before his proof that "It is clear from elementary considerations that any composite number can be resolved into prime factors, but it is often wrongly taken for granted that this cannot be done in several different ways". But even more than a couple centuries later rigor was still lacking in some textbooks. Indeed, [Harold Davenport wrote](http://books.google.com/books?id=pGDckKsed3EC&pg=PA19) that some British  schoolbooks deemed uniqueness of prime factorizations to be a "law of thought".

Comment: You are so detailed this time, I wish you could be always.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1850493/242)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this page extremely relevant: [Euclid's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Your statement `this implies that p is divided out by one of prime factors of ab` is unclear or even erroneous: you are saying that if $n$ is a prime factor of $ab$, then $n|p$ for some $n$.

Otherwise, your intuition looks good. Dustan made a pertinent comment about circularity.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. What I meant it to say was that if $p$ can divide $ab$ then if you prime factorize $ab$ then one of prime factors of $ab$ must cancel with $p$. I don't know how to describe this perfectly but I'm trying to describe it as you would do it on paper.