# contrapositive of the following logical statement

Tags: logic

What is the contrapositive of the following statement: 
$p|ab $ and $p|a$ or $p|b$ then $p$ is prime.

number theory problem

Comment: The '$p|ab$ and $p|a$ or $p|b$' part is ambiguous.

Comment: @GitGud *And* has precedence over *or*.

Comment: @TooOldForMath Since when?

Comment: @GitGud Thats just [how it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: @TooOldForMath Computer scientists..

Comment: The statement that you _intended_ to write might have been "if $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ for all $a$ and $b$, then $p$ is a prime". Written that way, it's almost true about the natural numbers (though it fails for $p=1$), but the position of the quantification over $a$ and $b$ is _crucial_, and leaving it out of the statement invites mistakes in forming the contrapositive.

Comment: ... Formally it would be: $(\forall a \forall b. p\mid ab \to (p\mid a \lor p\mid b))\to p\text{ is prime}$.

Comment: Hm.  I learned something new: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective (@GitGud)

Comment: @anorton The section about precedence seems to me like just a pictorial example and not meant to be taken seriously. I've never seen such a claim in any logic book and I'd welcome a few examples of this, if they exist.

Comment: @GitGud This is how it was meant. Don't take it too seriously.

Comment: @GitGud: It is just a convention, perhaps not universally observed, but nonetheless one that is prevalent in both mathematics and computer science. Of course, brackets are preferable.

Comment: @user21820 I'm just asking for proof from reliable sources (read mathematics books) that this is indeed a common convention.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive of

> $p|ab  \land (p|a \lor p|b) \Rightarrow p$ is prime

is

> $p$ is not prime $\Rightarrow p \not\mid ab \lor (p\not\mid a \land p\not\mid b)$.

But I don't think those are true statements...

Comment: You are right; in another post about [number theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638482/is-my-intuition-of-if-p-mid-ab-then-p-mid-a-or-p-mid-b-correct), it was proved that $\forall p \forall a \forall b (Prime(p) \rightarrow (p∣ab \rightarrow (p∣a \lor p∣b)))$. But if you have $p = 60$, $a = 60$ and $b = 10$, then $60|600$ and $60|60$, so that $p|ab \land (p|a \lor p|b)$ but $\lnot Prime(60)$.

Answer (score 0):

The *contrapositive* of $(P \rightarrow Q)$ is : $(\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P)$.

So, if we omit the initial quantifiers $\forall a \forall b \forall p$, we have :

> $( p|ab \rightarrow (p|a \lor p|b) ) \rightarrow Prime(p)$

Then the contrapositive must be :

> $(\lnot Prime(p) \rightarrow \lnot ( p|ab \rightarrow (p|a \lor p|b) )$.

Now, if we want to "unwind" also the inner conditional, we can take into account that : $(P \rightarrow Q)$ is equivalent to : $(\lnot P \lor Q)$, so that $\lnot (P \rightarrow Q)$, using De Morgan laws, becomes : $(\lnot \lnot P \land \lnot Q)$, and finally : $(P \land \lnot Q)$.

The translation now is :

> $(\lnot Prime(p) \rightarrow ( p|ab \land \lnot (p|a \lor p|b) )$

and finally :

> $(\lnot Prime(p) \rightarrow ( p|ab \land (\lnot p|a \land \lnot p|b) )$.

Comment: In my suggested interpretation the quantifiers $\forall a\forall b$ are NOT initial, but belong on the left of the $\to$. That makes the statement _almost_ true (and fully true if we redefine "prime" to include $1$).

Comment: @Henning Makholm - I'm sorry; I'll correct my answer. I supposed that the question was about the "logical machinery" and not about proving if the number theoretic statement was true or not.

Comment: @Henning Makholm - my "interpretation" was based on a previous post about [number theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638482/is-my-intuition-of-if-p-mid-ab-then-p-mid-a-or-p-mid-b-correct), i.e.checking that $( p \mid ab \rightarrow (p \mid a \lor p \mid b) )$, that is true only if $Prime(p)$ [if not, $60 \mid 6 \times 10$]. So, the theorem can be formalized as : $\forall p \forall a \forall b ( Prime(p) \rightarrow ( p \mid ab \rightarrow (p \mid a \lor p \mid b)) )$. I'm supposing that the OP is trying to prove the other "direction" of the "iff".

Comment: x @mauro: That has the implication going the other way.

Comment: @Henning - I understand your comment; my point of view is that, assuming that my reading of the OP's formula is correct, and if my *contraposition* is, we have that the formula is not *true*. Take $p = 60$, so that $\lnot Prime(p)$ is *true*, take $a = 60$ and $b = 10$, so that $p|ab$, but $60|60$, and so: $\lnot p|a$ is *false*. This shows that the formula above $[True \rightarrow (True \land (False \land True))]$ will get $False$. Having said that, under my initial "assumptions", we have that $\forall p \forall a \forall b ((p|ab \rightarrow (p|a \lor p|b)) \rightarrow Prime(p))$ is *false*.