# Why do we need to prove a fraction can always be written in lowest terms?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm currently reading the [notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf) of a preliminary Math course.

Section 3.1.1 contains some proofs using the Well Ordering Principle. One of them is about the always apparent possibility to write a fraction in shortest terms.

**But why does this require a proof?** If the fraction has no common factors it is already the result, and otherwise, I don't see any contradiction as to why this needs to be explicitly proved. Even if numerator and denominator have no GCD other than $1$, the fraction has a presentation in shortest terms, i.e., the fraction itsself!
So why prove this? What does it prove at all?

Furthermore, can any proof be superfluous at all?
I'm not that into mathematics and all (I like it nevertheless), so bear with me in case of any gross misunderstanding, please.

Comment: This statement is more or less equivalent to the statements that any two integers have a gcd. This is not obvious and really requires a proof, and one way to see this is that it's false in more general "number systems." For example, instead of the integers you can consider the integers together with the number $\sqrt{-5}$, and in this number system two numbers don't always have a gcd.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Two integers need not have a GCD, alright, so this is false, but even if a fraction's numerator and denominator do not have a GCD the fraction can still be written in lowest terms, i.e., **as is**. So, no matter if the fraction's parts have a GCD, the fraction has  a representation in lowest terms nevertheless. So, why does the fact I uttered in my question need to be proved anyway?

Comment: You say "the fraction can still be written in lowest terms, i.e., as is". What about the fraction $\frac24$? Are you sure you know what "lowest terms" means here?

Comment: @Downvoter: I'm not sure what you mean. Two integers always have a gcd. Sometimes that gcd is $0$; is that the case you were concerned about? Regarding your second question, you need to rule out the possibility that a fraction might *never* be expressible in lowest terms; maybe you keep dividing the numerator and denominator by stuff and the process never terminates. So there's something to prove in showing that this doesn't happen.

Comment: @GregMartin I mistook "no GCD" for GCD $ = 1$. I'll rephrase my question. Anyway, the GCD of $\frac24$ is $2$, so it can be written on lowest terms, which means "writable as  a fraction with a GCD $ = 1$" (right?). But $\frac37$, e.g., has no GCD other than $1$, so it is already on lowest terms.

Comment: For *those specific fractions*, you have observed how to write them in lowest terms. How do you know you can do that *for any possible fraction*? That's exactly what a proof is for. (And "lowest terms" does mean "their GCD equals 1". A GCD never equals 0.)

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, $ = 0$ was a typo, I just correct that. :-)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "Sometimes that gcd is $0$" How is that possible? $0 * x = 0$, right? Just to make sure we're on the same page, I'm solely referring to the numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. I indeed mistook "no GCD" for GCD $ = 1$ but I'll change that. "[...] a fraction might *never* be expressible in lowest terms" which is the case if GCD $ = 1$, right? If you have determined a GCD successfully, how can you " [...] keep dividing the numerator and denominator by stuff [...]"? What "stuff"? Random numbers?

Comment: @GregMartin If possible, could you point out an argument as to why a fraction could **not** be written in lowest terms? Maybe that helps me understand the matter.

Comment: Maybe this is the whole point: now that you're looking at the foundations of mathematics (which is a great thing to do), I think you need to practice setting aside your intuition that comes from doing arithmetic, and instead adopt a very strict foundational view of mathematics. In particular, that view does not require "arguments why something we're used to (because of the finitely many examples we've seen in our lives) couldn't happen". Instead, that foundational review requires proofs that things actually do always happen. That is an essential part of studying foundations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, which the section you're referencing plainly uses as an example, it is necessary:

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers such that $\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{2}$.
>
> Then $a^2=2b^2$.
>
> Since $2$ is prime, $2$ divides $a$, say $a=2c$.
>
> Going back to $a^2=2b^2$, we now have $4c^2=2b^2$, and then $2c^2=b^2$. Since $2$ divides $b^2$, $2$ divides $b$.

At this point in what has been written, there is no problem.

However, if you had *additionally assumed* that $a$ and $b$ have no common prime divisors, you would have reached a contradiction.

Otherwise, this argument does not get anywhere:

> say $b=2d$. Then $2c^2=4d^2\implies c^2=2d^2\implies 2|c$
>
> say $c=2e$. Then $4e=2d^2\implies 2e^2=d^2\implies 2|d$
>
> say $d=2f$. Then $2e^2=4f^2\implies e^2=2f^2\implies 2|e$
>
> ...

Comment: Yes, that's what I've also been thinking about. But why do we need to prove it? Isn't that deductible? PS: why can we just assume such a property about variables? Why can we just say the fraction is in lowest terms for variable numerators and denominators?

Comment: @Downvoter *Isn't that deductible?*  Of course it can be deduced, *that's what the proof is: a deduction of that fact.* Depending on the type of ring ("number system") you are working in, that statement may or may not hold. It does hold for the integers. You can't "just say" things have properties that you want. You could "just say" it has a property that causes a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure what "assuming property about variables" is. I just follow the axioms of set theory and the integers and the rationals.

Comment: The proof assumes that $a$ and $b$ constitute a fraction in lowest terms. Why can one just assume that? Couldn't you insert any value into $a$ or $b$, not just those making up a fraction on lowest terms?

Comment: @Downvoter: as guestDiego explained in the other answer, the point is that you can choose any representative from the *equivalence class* of fractions. Since $\frac12, \frac24, \frac36$, etc., all effectively represent the same object, we're allowed to choose the most convenient one for the purpose at hand. We might as well start off with the fraction that leads most quickly to a contradiction, and that means choosing one in lowest terms. There's nothing stopping us from starting with a fraction not in lowest terms, but then you have to show that there will *eventually* be a contradiction.

Comment: @Downvoter The author admitted that the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ assumed this fact, and it's probably the case that the author just omitted that for the purposes of exposition. That's why the author is looping back and pointing out that it is not explicitly written anywhere that such a selection is always possible, but you can use the WOP to *prove* it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It does require *rigorous proof* that fractions can be written in lowest form, (i.e. with coprime numerator and denominator), because this property is not always true for other types of numbers. Though a proof is obvious in the classical integer case, it can fail for fractions formed from other numbers. The classical proof depends *crucially* on the fact that $\,\Bbb N\,$ is well-ordered, so continually cancelling common factors must eventually terminate with a fraction in lowest terms (else the cancellations would yield an infinite decreasing sequence of denominators, contra $\,\Bbb N\,$ is well-ordered.

For other types of numbers there may exist $\,a,b,c\,$ where $\, c^k\,$ divides $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ for *all* $\,k\ge 0.\,$ Here the above proof breaks down for $\,a/b,\,$ since no matter how many times we cancel $\,c\,$ from the fraction, there will always remain a common factor of $\,c.$

In domains like elementary number theory where we have very strong intuition based on experience, it is especially important to be extra careful not to confuse empirical inference with logical inference. This occurred many times in the past.

For example, for many centuries no one noticed that uniqueness of prime factorizations required proof. Apparently either no one conceived of the possibility of nonuniqueness (or those who did thought that the proof was so "obvious" that it did not deserve mention). This was not corrected until $1801$ when Gauss plugged this gaping logical gap in his book [Disquisitiones Arithmeticae,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disquisitiones_Arithmeticae) where he wrote "It is clear from elementary considerations that any composite number can be resolved into prime factors, but it is often wrongly taken for
granted that this cannot be done in several different ways".

But even decades later one still finds mistakes made around unique factorization, even by leading number theorists. For example, circa $1850$ a few eminent mathematicians mistakenly thought they had proved FLT by erroneously assuming statements (e.g. Bezout arguments) that they did not realize were equivalent to unique factorization (which generally fails in the rings of cyclotomic integers studied). Even a century later rigor still was lacking in some expositions, e.g. [Harold Davenport wrote](http://books.google.com/books?id=pGDckKsed3EC&pg=PA19) that some British  schoolbooks deemed uniqueness of prime factorization to be a "law of thought".

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/638530/242)

Answer (score 1):

The question has to do with the concept of *equivalence classes*. A fraction is not an "operation", a division in 'progress'. This is a quite common intuitive picture for the beginners (and there is nothing  bad in that). Instead, a fraction is an equivalence class of 'pairs' (the equivalent 'fractions'): so, for example
$$
\frac{1}{2}=\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{6},\ldots\right]
$$
or, more correctly,
$$
\frac{1}{2}=\left[(1,2),(2,4),(3,6),\ldots\right].
$$
The symbol '$1/2$' has to be considered a *representative* of its class. But if we want to use only the representatives and not the underlying classes, we need to specify what representative we choose. Taking the 'minimal' fraction is an effective way to designate a 'canonical' representative.

Comment: Thanks to J.M. for the emendations in the text!

Comment: I know about fractions (I daresay) and that they have multiple representations, inter alia, one that is in lowest terms. But there's my problem: why would you need to **prove** the existence of that fraction in lowest terms, which represents the class?

Comment: I admit that I cannot completely understand your concern. I would say that having a special representative in place of a class is at least a very useful tool (see the example above about the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$). Anyway, this *proof* of the existence of the lowest-terms representative is not all this sensation...