# Let $n$ be an integer. If $n^2$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

I am trying to prove the statement "Let $n$ be an integer. If $n^2$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $3$." by using the direct proof technique.

The following is my proof.

---

Consider the following definition.

***Definition 5.1***: A nonzero integer $a$ divides an integer $b$ if there is an integer $j$ such that $b = aj.$

Because $3$ divides $n^2$, by ***Definition 5.1*** it follows that

\begin{align}
n^2 = 3j \text{ for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}

By taking the square root on both sides of the above equation, one obtains

\begin{align}
n = \pm \sqrt{3j} \text{ for some $j \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}

Since $n$ is an integer, for the $RHS$ of the above equation to be an integer, $j = 3k^2$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z^*}$.

Hence,

\begin{align}
n = \pm \sqrt{9k^2} = \pm 3k \text{ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z^*}$}
\end{align}

By ***Definition 5.1***, one can conclude that $3$ divides $n$.

---

Is the proof correct?

---

*Reference:*

*Reading, Writing, and Proving: a Closer Look at Mathematics*, by Ulrich Daepp and Pamela Gorkin, 2nd ed., Springer, 2011, pp. 52,55.

Comment: I think there's a potential circularity issue: you use the fact that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, but the most well-known proof of that depends on this fact. In any case it's a bit of a copout.

Comment: The easiest proof is based on Euklid's lemma for primes $p$ : If $p\mid ab$ , then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Apply this to the case $p=3$ and $a=b=n$.

Comment: Another way than the one given by @Peter using heavier artillery is by the prime number decomposition.

Comment: Just a minor typo: "By taking square" should be "By taking square root"

Comment: @Peter In english, the official language of this site, the name is Euclid.

Comment: @nicomezi That's an immediate consequence of Euclid's Lemma, so it is hardly "heavier" artillery.

Comment: So it is not heavier but it is ? @BillDubuque

Comment: Why do you believe "it is"?  Uniqueness of prime factorizations follows by a simple straightforward  inductive application of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: Because I believe that using a theorem coming from a lemma that you can use directly and (more ?) conveniently without having to reproof the theorem in some way is using heavier artillery. What is your interpretation on this ? @BillDubuque

Comment: @nicomezi They are equivalent, so either can be used to prove the other. Whether or not one is more convenient will depend on the context.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see the point of such nitpicking, you are now commenting the little thing in the parenthesis to make a point. Have a nice evening, I think we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof has a problem here

> Since $n$ is an integer, for the $RHS$ of the above equation to be an integer, $j = 3k^2$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z^*}$.

How do you know this?

Answer (score 2):

Your error was noted in the other answer.

---

You can apply [Proof by Contradiction:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#:%7E:text=In%20logic%20and%20mathematics%2C%20proof,false%20leads%20to%20a%20contradiction.)

- If $n=3k-1$, then $(3k-1)^2=9k^2-6k+1.$

This implies,

$$(3k-1)^2 \equiv 1 ~ \text{mod}~3$$

- If $n=3k-2$, then $(3k-2)^2=9k^2-12k+4.$

This implies,

$$(3k-2)^2 \equiv 1 ~ \text{mod}~3$$

Thus, it must be if and only if $n=3k$.

$$9k^2 \equiv 0~ \text{mod}~3$$

---

#### Generalization:

Let, $m$ be a prime number.

If, $n^2 \equiv 0~ \text{mod}~m$ , then if and only if $n=mk, k\in\mathbb Z.$

Comment: Downvoters ,please make a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE! Here's an alternate elementary proof

$$n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \implies 3 \mid n^2 $$

Thus  there's a factor of $3$ in $n^2$. Now it's very trivial that power of any prime in a perfect square is even, and hence power of $3$ in $n^2$ is even which implies that $3 \mid n$ and this concludes the proof. You can even generalize this for any number. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it is not "trivial" but depends on a deep result known as the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations) or closely related results. If you don't rigorously justify such claims then there is no way to determine if your proof is correct or not. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/638530/242) for more on this important matter

Comment: I don't think Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is a deep result... You can show it very easly with infinite division $n = a_0b_0 = a_1a_2b_1b_2 = a_1a_2a_3a_4b_1b_1b_3b_4 = ...$ This process must end, therefore you can break $n$ into primes.